# Array into whiptail menu - BASH

Tags: bash, menu, dialog, whiptail

I would like to show user friendly `whiptail` menu.

My goal in `whiptail` is this:

```
Choice1
Choice2
Choice3
Choice4
```

I have array consist of:

```
Choice1 Choice2 Choice3 Choice4
```

I run array through loop for like this:

```
for value in ${value[@]}
do
    echo "$value"
done
```

I could not add `whiptail` inside echo because I get 4 another menus.

I tried script like this:

```
$val=$(whiptail --title "xx" --menu "choose" 16 78 10
for value in ${value[@]}
do
    echo "$value"
done
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

After run above mentioned script my shell looks horrible.

shell after script:

[image]

Is there anybody who solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is several errors in your script, e.g. you should not give the loop iterator the same name as array itself. However your don't need any loop for this task, just put all array elements at once with special array index `@`:

```
value=(Choice1 "" Choice2 "" Choice3 "" Choice4 "")
whiptail --title "xx" --menu "choose" 16 78 10 "${value[@]}"
```

Notice empty string inside quotes `""` - this is description required by `whiptail` menu option, without that you would treat `Choice` and `Choice4` as description:

```
Choice1 Choice2
Choice3 Choice4
```

what is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is what I wanted to avoid. I have got another solution. Do you know how to duplicate records in array? I am gonna run through whiptail as you described and set `--notag`.

Comment: @MichalN. What do you mean by "duplicate"? You want repeat all elements one more time in the same order or add neighbor to each element?

Comment: @jimmj Yes, all elements in the same order.

Comment: @MichalN. `new=("${value[@]}" "${value[@]}")`

Comment: @jimmj I did not express myself corectly - my mistake. I want output duplicated output like this: `Choice1 Choice1 Choice2 Choice2 Choice3 Choice3  Choice4 Choice4` instead `Choice1 Choice2 Choice3 Choice4 Choice1 Choice2 Choice3 Choice4`

Comment: Found another solution. Duplicated choices as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a checkbox menu:

```bsh
checkboxes () 
{ 
    local -A checkboxes;
    checkboxes["foo"]=off;
    checkboxes["bar"]=on;
    checkboxes["eric"]=on;

    backtitle="Backtitle";
    title="Title";
    question="Please choose:";

    choices=();
    for key in "${!checkboxes[@]}";
    do
        choices+=("$key" "" "${checkboxes[$key]}");
    done;

    result=$(
        whiptail --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                 --title "$title"         \
                 --checklist "$text"      \
                 0 0 0 "${choices[@]}"    \
                 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3-
    );
    echo "$result"
}
```